# Problems to send internal table to SAP ERP with SAPNWRFC

Tags: php, abap

I am sending an internal table to an ABAP function with SAPNWRC but I have problems with it. For example, if I send one array to my `itab` with 3 values, it works but if I send one array with 4 values or more it does not work. This is my code:

The following piece of code works:

```
$input_parameters = [
            'S_PSPID' => $strctr_project,
            'T_PPTOBASE' => [
                [
                'PSPNR' => '30964',
                'PSPHI' => '394',
                'WLGEV' => '0'
                ],
                [
                'PSPNR' => '30965',
                'PSPHI' => '394',
                'WLGEV' => '0'
                ],
                [
                'PSPNR' => '30966',
                'PSPHI' => '394',
                'WLGEV' => '0'
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $function  = $connection -> function_lookup('ZFUNCTION');
        $itab_proj = $function -> invoke($input_parameters);
        $itab_proj = $itab_proj['T_TABLE'];
```

On the other hand this does not:

```
$input_parameters = [
                'S_PSPID' => $strctr_project,
                'T_PPTOBASE' => [
                    [
                    'PSPNR' => '30964',
                    'PSPHI' => '394',
                    'WLGEV' => '0'
                    ],
                    [
                    'PSPNR' => '30965',
                    'PSPHI' => '394',
                    'WLGEV' => '0'
                    ],
                    [
                    'PSPNR' => '30966',
                    'PSPHI' => '394',
                    'WLGEV' => '0'
                    ],
                    [
                    'PSPNR' => '30967',
                    'PSPHI' => '394',
                    'WLGEV' => '0'
                    ],

                ]
            ];
```

**Error:** SapnwrfcConnectionException An invalid handle was passed to the API call

Comment: What error message do you get from this `ZFUNCTION` function module?

Comment: The browser only are loading and after shows the error sapnwrfcConnectionException An invalid handle was passed to the API call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I solved my problem installing SAP NW RFC SDK extension for PHP7.